# how to put avalaible value to designated cell

Tags: excel

I'm having some trouble here.
I have an excel test.
The instruction is to adding a final value with an available value, and it should using trim(instruction unclear but it just said "TRIM" on the sheet test.

The data is look like these.
Btw, what is the function in excel to fill the final score but skip the blank(Actually if it with trim)?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, *really* **must** use `Trim()`, you might opt for following solution:

```
=TRIM(A1&B1)
```

It means that you are using both cells "A1" and "B1" as strings, you concatenate them and trim it, so, in case either one of them contains only space characters, those get chopped off.

Comment: This is solve my problem... its what i looking for :).... THANKSS>>
the instruction is Must use trim ..

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty easier. `MAX()` may work for you.

```
=MAX(C2:D2)
```

For Microsoft 365 user can use `BYROW()` for array approach.

```
=BYROW(C2:D16,LAMBDA(x,MAX(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: i thought max is used to choose the maximum value only...
did you have another reccomendation function or any other relative to trim?

Comment: As per your data sample `MAX()` must work. Try it. If your actual data is different then could suggest formula based on dataset.